# Job -l after nohup

Tags: linux, bash, nohup

How can I monitor a job that is still running (I guess detached?) after I started it with nohup, exited the server and logged back in?  Normally, I use `jobs -l` to see what's running, but this is showing blank.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to understand the [difference between a process and a job](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4214/what-is-the-difference-between-a-job-and-a-process). Jobs are managed by the shell, so when you end your terminal session and start a new one, you are now in a new instance of Bash with its own jobs table. You can't access *jobs* from the original shell but as the other answers have noted, you can still find and manipulate the *processes* that were started. For example:

```
$ nohup sleep 60 &
[1] 27767
# Our job is in the jobs table
$ jobs
[1]+  Running                 nohup sleep 60 &
# And this is the process we started
$ ps -p 27767
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
27767 pts/1    00:00:00 sleep
$ exit # and start a new session
# Now jobs returns nothing because the jobs table is empty
$ jobs
# But our process is still alive and kicking...
$ ps -p 27767
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
27767 pts/1    00:00:00 sleep
# Until we decide to kill it
$ kill 27767
# Now the process is gone
$ ps -p 27767
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
```

Comment: Yep, thanks, that's precisely the difference I needed to understand.

Answer (score 2):

You can monitor if the proceses if still running using

`ps -p <pid>`, where  is the ID of the process you get after using the `nohup` command.

If you see valid entries you process is probably alive.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a list of the processes running under current user with `ps -u "$USER"` or `ps -u "$(whoami)"`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
ps -ef | grep <pid>
```